# Is there a logging service in AWS for debug information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm trying out AWS. I create a app that is running in an EC2 instance. I want to send debug/diagnostic logs to stdout or syslog and have some way to easily collect and let me read them.

Currently I use Stackdriver logging, I install a google-fluentd plugin in the EC2 instance and it picks up the syslog and send to Stackdriver. I'm wondering whether there is a similar offering in AWS so that I don't need to create a GCP project just for reading logs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS allows you dump all your logs to cloud watch where you can store them click [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) to be redirected to the corresponding aws documentation. The documentation teaches you how to set up the ec2 machine in order to dump the logs to aws

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [AWS Cloudwatch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance.html) in your EC2 Instance. The agent then allows you to ship custom log files to AWS Cloudwatch. From AWS cloudwatch you could analyze them. You could also ship system and application logs through the agent. Here is a [blog post](https://medium.com/@rifhan.akram1/monitoring-and-alerting-on-premise-iis-hosted-application-availability-with-aws-cloudwatch-2b16aecaf0f4) explaining how it could be done on a Windows machine not hosted in AWS, its pretty much the same approach for a EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Cloud watch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) to monitor, store, and access your log files from Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances, AWS CloudTrail, Route 53, and other sources. You can then retrieve the associated log data from CloudWatch Logs.